# Is this how header/implementation files work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I asked this question earlier and I have been reading the answers and searched more information about header and implementation files. Coming from Java I have not seen this separation before and I wonder if I have understood it correctly, so here it goes:

Function declarations is needed at the of a source file so you can use function declaration independent of where they are defined in the file. The parser reads top-down (not sure if this is the case anymore?)

Instead of having them in the implementation source they are moved out to a own file (Header). This header file is instead included with the preprocessor and are copied/pasted by the machine instead. The header file may also include other headers but I read something about including other headers in the main file instead?

Then the source file is compiled. And afterwards it is linked. Is that correct?

Comment: You basically have it.  For separate compilation units in any C-derived language (including C++ and Objective-C) the compiler "prefers" to have every entity declared before it's used.  (It will assume defaults in some cases, but not always the ones you'd like.)  But if you must include the "real" code in a separate compilation, in order to tell the compiler about these entities, then you've rendered meaningless the separate compilation scheme, so you include declarations that are a sort of template of the separately-compiled code.

Comment: (Note that Java is relatively unusual in not requiring this.  Most other compiled languages have some sort of requirement for declaring the interfaces to separate compilation units.  Java gets around this need by extracting the equivalent info from the .class files of the referenced entities when compiling your source.)

Comment: @HotLicks Ok! But after the .m/.cpp files is compiled to object code how do they find the definition of the function that it may included from another header file? How is the linker able to do this? And is it merged into one big object file or are they kept separate?

Comment: Every compiled, linkable program file contains a "dictionary" that lists it's "exports" (mostly callable functions).  Either as a separate "linking" step or while "loading" prior to execution (iPhone uses separate linking) this dictionary is consulted and any references to entry points in it from other compiled modules are "resolved" by creating the appropriate pointer from one compiled module to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much. IDE's used to develop in C# and Java (and in dynamic languages the interpreter too, e.g. Ruby) dynamically create a list of functions that are accessible in a given class based on the class definition (specifically based on the public/private/protected modifiers). In ObjectiveC we don't have those modifiers (or at least not until recently) and the .h file is essentially a way of listing only those variables and methods that should be used by other classes.

In other words, the compiler is using the .h files to cache declarations that are accessible for other classes (including child classes that inherit those declarations from the base class).

That said, it's not the whole picture because in ObjectiveC methods are being called dynamically. For example you don't need to specify a declaration in .h file for another class to be able to call a method that is only defined in .m file. In Java references to specific methods are resolved at compile time. When a method is not defined then another code can't call it. In ObjectiveC when a piece of code calls a method it is in fact sending a message to the class to execute that method. At the time of execution the dispatcher checks if an object responds to that message and if yes, calls that method. This is of course a simplification. Check the Wikipedia page about [ObjectiveC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) for more details (especially section Messages).

The separation between declaration and definition comes from C. One function or variable may have many declarations but only one definition. When .h file is imported at the beginning of .m file its content is effectively being added to that .m file during compilation (together with other .h files referenced in those files). If for example file `a.m` was to be imported to files `b.m` and `c.m` then effectively during compilation both `b.m` and `c.m` would have duplicated definitions of variables and methods defined in `a.m` (for example a variable defined in `a.m` would be stored at different addresses when `a.m` was imported and then compiled in `b.m` or `c.m`).

Comment: Actually, the "list of (accessible) functions" in Java is quite static -- essentially determined at javac time.

Comment: Sure, I rather had in mind the IDE. For example Eclipse will use the definitions to autocomplete or tell the user that a method is private and can't be used. The same in C# and Visual Studio. In XCode methods defined in .m file can't be directly referenced in other .m files unless explicitly listed in an .h file. But it is smart enough to autocomplete methods that can be called due to the messaging mechanism even though they are not explicitly declared, e.g. button actions referenced by selectors.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, fair point. I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Basically, in Java, the .class file stands in for the .h file in C-derived languages, the .def in Modula-2, etc, both in an IDE and during separate compilation.